# Изменение свойств получаемого .exe файла в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть проект в `Delphi 7`, после его построения получаю .exe файл-программу. Затем, правой кнопкой мыши, открываю свойство .exe файла, на вкладке "Подробно", и вижу свойства "Авторские права, Организация и Версия файла". Как можно изменить эти параметры до получения exe-файла на этапе компиляции в среде `Delphi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project->Options все пишется там